# do the meta-data / data-lineage app have APIs for external datasources?

Tags: cdap

Our project is on AWS and we are already using different AWS services for our data-pipeline. So Would like to know if we can push those info into your meta-data/Data-lineage(FFL) apps?

-VVS

Answer (score 0):

CDAP currently do not have support for pushing external metadata into CDAP. If you have more details about your use case, you can do a feature request through the CDAP mailing list: cdap-user@googlegroups.com